# Cannot set "connect a host virtual adapter to this network" VMware(Network config)

Tags: networking, vmware

I installed Ubuntu on the Vmware workstation. 
After that I tried configure Network. (Edit->Virtual Network Editor).
I show [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/undSU.png)

When I submit it and tap on the Apply,  the driver is dedicated to the device manager (VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet). But when the download ends the driver disappears and the values(connect a host virtual adapter to this network) are not again selected.

Thanks in advance